I would like to understand the role of the parameter 'row' in the function computePointSPFHSignature() from pcl
void computePointSPFHSignature(
        const pcl::PointCloud &cloud,
        const pcl::PointCloud &normals, 
        pcl::index_t p_idx, 
        int row,
        const pcl::Indices &indices,
        Eigen::MatrixXf &hist_f1,
        Eigen::MatrixXf &hist_f2, 
        Eigen::MatrixXf &hist_f3)
{}

The function is from the ‘fpfh.h’ file. Shouldn't the SPFH histogram be one-dimensional? What is the role of the parameter 'row'? Is it typically set to 0 in practical use?
I want to understand the specific meaning and usage details of 'row'.

The documentation (fpfh.h) describes it as: "row - the index row in feature histograms".
The feature histograms are "Eigen::MatrixXf" objects. The columns in the histogram represent the bins. In which row of the matrix the bins are used is specified by the parameter "row" hist_f1 (row, h_index) += hist_incr;.
This way the function can be executed several times and all histograms can be written into one matrix. These can then be further processed later.
The unit test also shows this. The unit test (test_pfh_estimation.cpp) shows that this parameter is used to store the result of different indices. It is also used by computeSPFHSignatures in this way.
So if you only call this function once, always set row to 0. If you use the function several times and need to compare/process the results later, you can use one matrix object and specify the row to be used for each call.

I believe I have understood what you said, thank you very much.
